# OpenERP - How to get sequence number when creating new Sales Order via XMLRPC

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo, sequences

I'm making an Android app for OpenERP and I'm trying to create new Sales Order. One of the required fields however is Order Reference, which is normaly generated from the sequence.

Is there some way to get this sequence via xmlrpc?

Or do I have to make my own sequence in the app? ...but then how can I make sure that it would not colide with order references generated via web client?

Thank you.

Comment: this is NOT [android]-related question.

Comment: I removed the tag even though for me it was an [android]-related question... but I can see your point

Comment: ok, what have you tried so far? What does it mean `generated from the sequence`? What kind of `sequence` are we talking about?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet...I'm analysing the problem first. In OpenERP there are sequences which are generating values for some fields like the order reference in Sales Order (SO001, SO002, ...).
When you create new SO in webclient it prepopulates the order reference field with value generated with the sequence.

My first idea is to create my own sequencer in the app that would generate slightly different sequence (e.g. SOA001, SOA002, ...) and only check the result of write xmlrpc request.

But that would make two different styles of order references...

Comment: which openerp version you are using ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to do anything special: just call `sale.order`'s `create` method with the content of your Sales Order. As you noticed when you create a Sales Order using the web interface, the reference field is automatically filled in with a proper sequence number.

This happens because `sale.order` has a default value for the reference field (the `sale.order`'s `name` field, technically). Default values work as follows:

- they are fetched by the client UI to pre-populate the creation form. The client obtains these value by calling [`default_get`](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.default_get) on the corresponding model (which will take the values from the `_defaults` dictionary.
- when the [create](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.create) method is called to create a new record, the system will call [default_get](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.default_get) again in order to complete the values for all the fields that have defaults and were not explicitly passed to [create](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/api_models/#openerp.osv.orm.BaseModel.create)

As a result, you don't need to do anything: just call `create` without giving a value for the `name` field, and the system will automatically set its value to a valid sequence number, just as it would in the UI. Alternatively if you'd like to pre-process the default values or to exactly mimic what the UI does, then you should call `default_get` yourself via XML-RPC and use the returned values to prepare the parameters you will pass to `create`.

**Version note:** you did not mention any specific OpenERP version, and the actual behavior may vary a little bit depending on the version. In OpenERP 6.1 the `sale.order` model did exactly what I described above, as you can see in the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/7189/sale/sale.py#L273). In OpenERP 7.0 however the logic was slightly modified to avoid consuming sequence numbers that might never be used (if the user cancels before saving): instead of generating a new number in `default_get`, the `name` field is initialized to `'/'` by [default](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/8912/sale/sale.py#L254), and the `create` method replaces it with a new number, as you can see in the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/8912/sale/sale.py#L338). The net effect is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's exactly what I need. At the moment I'm using 6.1 but it's valuable to know about the different behavior in 7.0. Thanks